# powershell webclient uploadfile # in filename

Tags: powershell, webclient, filenames

Hi I just tested around with powershell Webclient.
Everthing seemed to work fine, but then i had to upload a file with a **#** in the name (**test.#00**).
The File on the Server just strips the .#00. The file on the server is named **"test"** instead of **"test.#00"**. The test.zip works without any problems.

Here is my Script used on Powershell Windows 10:

```
$webclient = New-Object System.Net.WebClient 
$localPath = "c:\temp\";
$ftp = "ftp://192.168.0.202/"

$webclient.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential("admin","admin")  
$webclient.UploadFile($ftp + "test.zip",$localPath +  "test.zip") 
$webclient.UploadFile($ftp + "test.#00",$localPath +  "test.#00")
```

Comment: Tried to escape the #? `#

Comment: Yes i tried this, although i am really new to Powershell and only used this for this simple script and i didn't know if i escaped it correctly. `# doesn't work!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @kirill mentioned, you have to hex encode the file name. You can also do this programmatically using `[uri]::EscapeDataString("test.#00")`

```
C:\> get-item .\test.#00

    Directory: C:\

Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
-a----        7/20/2017   7:23 AM              0 test.#00

C:\> $file = get-item .\test.#00
C:\> $encFileName = [uri]::EscapeDataString($file.Name)
C:\> $encFileName
test.%2300
C:\>
```

Answer (score 3):

Special characters as #,@,: in URLs have to be hex encoded.

where 23 is the hex value (0x23) of '#'

```
Character    Hex Conversion
#            %23
space        %20
@            %40
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice I guess this was the problem!